# document is missing mandatory uniquekey field id

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using solr4.6.1

I want to index static data and also have defined id field as uniquekey. still it gives error while debugging that is "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
and not adding data to index.

Comment: plz, specify stacktrace? need more concrete error message

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#im-getting-a-bad-request-error-when-calling-commit